# WooCommerce 4.1+ Geolocation / Geo_IP and Maxmind GeoLite2?

Tags: class, woocommerce, geolocation, settings, maxmind

I was in the Woocommerce settings and noticed I had "Default customer location" set to "No location by default". There is a Maxmind GeoLite Database they mention that I can use. However I'm already using the class:

```
new WC_Geolocation();
```

and it's working. Could someone explain to me how this works?

The above class is free and I don't need to pay for it, correct?

If Maxmind is a different service, why do others use it? Why not use the free built in class instead?

Answer (score 1):

Maxmind GeoLite2 **is FREE**.

Since WooCommerce 4.1 things are changing and you have now to [signup for Maxmind GeoLite2](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geolite2/signup). It will allow you to generate GeoLite2 license key, that you will set in woocommerce > Settings > Integration:

[image]

> Everything is explained on this official documentation: [MaxMind Geolocation Integration](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/maxmind-geolocation-integration/)

Comment: So then new WC_Geolocation(); does connect to MaxMind?

Comment: Yes, once you have follow the steps explained in the linked documentation, as MaxMind Geolite2 has been integrated in WooCommerce…

Comment: Sorry @LoicTheAztec! It is correct and thank you!! I've been working like crazy so I forgot to accept it :P